# Why the behaviour of CloudFormation DependsOn is inconsistent given the same template

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

From my understanding, the same CloudFormation template should result in the same behaviour when creating or deleting resources. However, I found out this is not true. The order you apply a template matters as well.

The case is, that I created EIP and NLB via CDK first, then I created a custom resource with the `DependsOn` attribute via CDK. After the creation was completed, I got the CloudFormation template as follows:

```json
{
  "Resources": {
    "loadbalancer": {
      ...
      "Properties": {
        "SubnetMappings": [
          {
            "AllocationId": {
              "Fn::GetAtt": [
                "eipA",
                "AllocationId"
              ]
            }
            ...
          }
          ...
        }
      }
      "DependsOn": [
        "customresourceA",
        ...
      ]
    },
    "eipA": {
      ...
    },
    "customresourceA": {
      ...
      "Properties": {
        "ElasticIp": {
          "Ref": "eipA"
        }
      }
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

Based on this template, I assume the dependency is as follows:

- loadbalancer depends on eipA and customresourceA
- customresourceA depends on eipA

The desired order of stack creation should be:

- eipA -> customresourceA -> loadbalancer

**The desired order of stack deletion should be:**

- **loadbalancer -> customresourceA -> eipA**

However, when I performed stack deletion, CloudFormation deleted `loadbalancer` and `customresourceA` at the same time. It seems like CloudFormation ignored the `DependsOn` field of `loadbalancer` resource.

[image]

But, if I create EIP, NLB, and custom resources at once, CloudFormation can perform deletion in the correct order.

[image]

---

I have an example, you can deploy and destroy CloudFormation Stack and observe this inconsistent behaviour.

https://github.com/Willis0826/cdk-cr-dependency-issue

Comment: Your understand and expectation are correct, this is some weird behavior. I suggest opening a support ticket.

Comment: Unfortunately, my account can't open a tech support ticket.
I also have a post on re:Post, but it seems like AWS is not interested in this issue.

https://repost.aws/questions/QUoKo-d5AUQK2W6SzKTuTD5A/the-behaviour-of-cloudformation-dependson-is-inconsistent-given-the-same-template

Comment: Has this issue affected you in some way?

Comment: I expect the load balancer was destroyed, and then CloudFormation Custom Resource invokes Lambda to sleep for 50 seconds. After 50 seconds, we delete the EIP.  (Because after you deleted the load balancer, it still takes some time before the EIP is released)
  
In this case, we can potentially update the logic of Lambda to work around this. But I guess that means we can't trust the order of CloudFormation with Custom Resource.

Comment: Heya guys, any feedback is welcome

Comment: I would still open a ticket even though it's not strictly "tech support" and they should give an answer

Answer (score -1):

Please modify the dependency of LB to only include "customresourceA".

So, The dependency should be structured as follows:

1. loadbalancer depends on customresourceA
   (It means the Load Balancer (LB) will wait for the Elastic IP Address (EIPA) inside 'customresourceA' to become available first, and once 'customresourceA' is ready, the last component to be initialized will be the LB.)
2. customresourceA depends on eipA

eipA -> customresourceA -> loadbalancer

Comment: Hey, thank you for your kind reply! The dependency has already been the same as your suggestion "eipA -> customresourceA -> loadbalancer". Sorry, perhaps I didn't explain well. The dependency was managed by CDK. Therefore, when the CDK realised the EIP needed to be attached to LB, it created a dependency including EIP for LB automatically. Did you mean if the dependency of LB only includes CustomResource, it will fix the unexpected deletion behaviour?

Comment: Yes, it's what I mean.Try to modify the dependency of LB only including CustomResource.

Comment: The dependency was managed by CDK, and the LB does depend on EIP. I am not sure why we need to remove EIP from the dependency of LB.

Comment: Because loadbalancer depends on customresourceA which already depends on eipA.

Comment: Hey Petersue, thanks for getting back! Yes, what you are saying makes sense. But, CloudFormation should be able to figure out these dependencies, right?

Comment: Apply action should be fine, but when you try to destroy it, which dependency should be destroyed first if there's the same dependency associated with two AWS services. Try to modify it, it should work.

Comment: This will have no effect. Regarding your question - the removal order will be the same.